# How to randomly stratify sampling within landcover classes?

Tags: raster, r, landsat-8, accuracy, image-classification

I'm working on an accuracy assessment of a classified landsat image and I'd like input on the best possible way to generate random points across both the classified image and a ground truth image I created by processing vector data from aerial photo interpretation.

I've processed both images and converted them to vectors in R and would like to generate random points in specific landcovers across both images so I can compare the predicted vs. actual landcover value at each random site.

My methodology so far has been to compare both vectors (in their entirety) and create a confusion matrix on them but the images this would include the training pixels in the supervised classification so I'd rather not have them as part of the accuracy assessment. A smaller subset of assessment pixels is probably best but I'd like feedback on those who have done this in R in the past as to best practices.

What approach should I take to generate random pixels in each image so I can compare the landcover values?

Comment: Use a randomly stratified sampling design: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/200263_e77d00d6b6b24aa8890c8c4f074bcdff.html

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'd also like to generate a certain number of random points inside each landcover type value.  I also need to be able to generate and pull the random points across both images (same random points for each image)

Comment: Use your land over classes as the zones. In the example that I referenced, they use counties as zones.

Comment: This example is on a vector layer.  My landcover zones are a raster layer.   With pixel values not boundaries. Not sure if it will work on my images

Comment: Have you looked at the `sampleStratified()` function in the `raster` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It s best to avoid converting to vector to do the sampling if you do not have to. You can use the `sampleStratified()` function in the [raster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package to generate randomly stratified points in your land cover classes. For example:

```
library(raster)

# Generate some sample landcover raster data
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
names(r) <- 'stratum'
values(r) <- round((runif(ncell(r))+0.5)*3)

# Randomly sample within each class (do not sample in NA)
s <- sampleStratified(r, size=3, na.rm=TRUE)

# Convert cell number to XY coords
xy <- xyFromCell(r,s) 

# Plot data
plot(r, col = topo.colors(3))
points(xy)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok I got the accuracy assessment to work but realize that rather than a Stratified Random Sample I would like a Proportional Stratified Random Sample based on landcover class value totals across the entire image.

Comment: I would recommend opening a new question on that.